# Update user meta every 10 minutes

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I created some custom user meta and it has a value in it. I want that value or what ever value the users have in it to be updated and replaced with the word "Lock down" every 10 minutes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this code below and got an errors..        


function update_users_megakey(){
update_user_megakey($user_id, 'change_mega_value', time() + 600 * 00 * 00 *00);

Comment: What errors exactly? And how did you use that function? You need to give us some more details so we can help you out.

Comment: By the way, multiplying `600 * 00 * 00 * 00` won't work...

Comment: You can achieve that with using cron job

Comment: Please how do i write a cron job function for it

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but maybe using a cron job for that is overkill.
If you just want to adjust the display of the value according to when the value is updated, you can pass the updated date to this value as an array.
For example:

// ON Save
$array = ['value' => 'myValue', 'time' => time()];
update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'test', $array);
// On Display
$val = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'test', true);
$ten_minute_ago = strtotime("-10 minutes");
if($val['time']<$ten_minute_ago){
    echo 'expired';
}else{
    echo 'not expired';
}

Comment: Thanks @Robin But your code is targeted at specific time when the value was entered,  meaning entries that is not to 10 mins will be spared, but what i want is that my website as a whole updates all the users meta value and replace it with a default word "Go Glow".

Comment: Lets say i have 600 users on my website,  and i created a registration form with the metakey user_phone so during registration the user type their phone number and save, and this saved phone numbers is stored in the user meta key called user_phone ... Now i want my sites to update or clear up all the different phone numbers each user added to his profile and replace it with a default word " Go Ahead" this will keep updating every 10mins and is a default time, meaning that if a user just type registered in 1mins before the set time , his data too will be cleaned up

Comment: All i need it how to write an update function,  target a specific meta key that should be affected with the update,  set a default word that will replace existing value or can just clean it up and leave it empty, lastly set how minutes the intervals will the function keep executing

Comment: So, make a cron job. I post an answer because code is too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

To do a cron job that runs every ten minutes, here is an example of code:

You can use https://generatewp.com to generate function like this

```php
// Schedule Cron Job Event
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_cron_job' );
function my_custom_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'ten_minutes', 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron' );
    }
}

// Scheduled Action Hook
add_action( 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron', 'myprefix_update_user_phone' );
function myprefix_update_user_phone( ) {
    // Do what you want
    error_log('TEST MY CRON');
}

// Custom Cron Recurrences
function custom_cron_job_recurrence( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['ten_minutes'] = array(
        'display' => __( 'Every 10 minutes', 'textdomain' ),
        'interval' => 600,
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin Zecka Ferrari, your code worked as expected, just that your function was meant to throw an error log at the set time, which is exactly what i wanted, but i want to change the function to update users website url and i did the modification below but it didn't work for me, please help....

Comment: i am pasting the code i tried using the normal comment box because of space

Answer (score 0):

```
// Schedule Cron Job Event
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_cron_job' );
function my_custom_cron_job() {
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'ten_minutes', 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron'     );
}
}

// Scheduled Action Hook
add_action( 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron', 'myprefix_update_user_phone' );
function myprefix_update_user_phone( ) {
// Do what you want
$website = 'http://wordpress.org';
update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_url', $website);
}

// Custom Cron Recurrences
function custom_cron_job_recurrence( $schedules ) {
$schedules['ten_minutes'] = array(
    'display' => __( 'Every 10 minutes', 'textdomain' ),
    'interval' => 300,
);
return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence' );
```

Comment: But this code is not working, Please can you help me fix only the Scheduled Action Hook, and make it to update user_url. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your goal... On myprefix_update_user_phone function you use a variable $user_id but this variable is not set. If you want to update all users maybe you can try something like 
$users = get_users();
foreach($users as $user){
 $website = 'http://wordpress.org';
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_url', $website);
}

Comment: `// Scheduled Action Hook
add_action( 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron', 'myprefix_update_user_phone' );
function myprefix_update_user_phone( ) {
    // Do what you want
 $users = get_users(); 
 foreach($users as $user){ 
    $website = 'wordpress.org'; 
    myprefix_update_user_phone($user->ID, '$user_url', $website);
    }
}`

Comment: That was what i added yet is not working, let me post it as answer for clarity so you can see the code and know why is not updating users url .

Comment: @RobinZecKaFerrari - That was what i added yet is not working, let me post it as answer for clarity so you can see the code and know why is not updating users url .

Answer (score 0):

```
// Scheduled Action Hook
add_action( 'myprefix_update_user_phone_cron', 'myprefix_update_user_phone' );
function myprefix_update_user_phone( ) {
    // Do what you want
    $users = get_users(); 
    foreach($users as $user){ 
    $website = 'wordpress.org'; 
    myprefix_update_user_phone($user->ID, '$user_url', $website);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is how i added the code but is not yet working, please help.